# Problems on xml to json convertion using org.json library

Tags: java, json, xml, org.json

We have used `org.json` library to convert xml data to json data

the code is very simple like below

```
JSONObject obj = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
```

In some cases it throws exception as

`org.json.JSONException: JSON does not allow non-finite numbers.`

We are processing huge amount of data at a time. there is more above ten thousand xml data are converting to json data. But a 10 or 15 are failing and throws the exception I mentioned above.

But when I took that xml file which throws the exception and run it as a single data it get succeed. We cannot figure out why is this happenning. If anyone used this library please give some advices.

Comment: I've had this issue before. It turned out the cause was there were `null` values. Are there any `null` values in your JSON?

Comment: No..I have logged out the xml and run it as single, then it worked. When bulk processing it fails

Comment: Could you provide the whole stack-trace